# Find the next word after a word in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to record the word after a specific word. For example, let's say I have a string:

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Email: John.Doe@email.com
```

I want to search the string for a key word such as "First Name:". Then I want to only capture the next word after it, in this case John.

I started using `string.find("First Name:")`, but I do not think that is the correct approach.

I could use some help with this. Most examples either split the string or keep everything else after "John". My goal is to be able to search strings for specific keywords no mater their location.

SOLUTION: 
I used a similar set of code as below:

```
search = r"(First Name:)(.)(.+)"
x = re.compile(search)
```

This gave me the "John" with no spaces

Comment: Why not you use dictionary instead?

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 2):

a regular expression is the way to go

```
import re 
pattern = r"(?:First Name\: ).+\b" 
first_names = re.findall(pattern, mystring)
```

It will find the prefix (First name: ) without extracting r"(?:First Name: )
then extracts .+\b which denotes a word. Or you can split the string and itterate over resulting list

```
my_words = [ x.split()[0] for x in  my_string.split("First Name: ")]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.find` approach is a good start.
You can use split on the remaining string to limit results to the single word.

Without using regex

```
s = "abc def opx"
q = 'abc'
res = s[s.find(q)+len(q):].split()[0]

res == 'def'
```